# An Iteration with renaming and avoiding duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Want to insert all the Rows of a table in a new table with a renaming activity.
Also we have some exceptions that we shouldn't move them.

`Renaming Act` : Change the char '_' into ' '

`Exceptions`   : Items that if we rename they would be duplicates in the new table.

So all the items there would be unique and renamed version of our previous table.

- Here we don't have any integer ID's,
- The database is SQL Server CE

---

- Our Tables : Product, tblNew
- Each with same columns : "Product", "col1", "col2"

Want to move the records to tblNew , our key column that we don't want duplicates is "product"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Column1)
    SELECT  REPLACE(OriginalColumn, '_', '')
      FROM  Table2 t2
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.Column1 = REPLACE(OriginalColumn, '_', '')
     WHERE  t1.Column1 IS NULL  -- Not a duplicate Record
```

Comment: Hi, if it works because of the CE version's disabilities it will be an awesome answer, will try it in minutes.

Comment: @Sypress: Previous Query doesn't seem to run on CE. The above query should run on CE.